# Salesforce, send email to multiple email address through a package

Tags: salesforce

I am new to Salesforce development and so would greatly appreciate any help for the following:
We have a Payment center app (somewhat like Zuora) that does invoicing and billing. Now this packaged app has a scheduler that sends reminders for declined credit cards etc daily at 5:00am.
What we are trying to achieve is that we have 3 email address fields (one standard and two custom) on Account. We want the email to be sent to all three addresses. 
Since it is being run by sheduler that sends a number of reminders so am not sure how to do it.
One way I was thinking was to have a workflow rule on task object so that whenever an email with "Failed Payment" is created then it should send an email alert to the other two other email addresses. What I am not sure about is how to include those email addresses in email alert?

Thanks!

Comment: could you show what have you tried so far

Comment: I haven't created an email alert as I was unable to add the secondary email fields. The scheduler is part of the managed package so am not sure how can I tweak it's email details